# Ansible code to restart Apache

Tags: ansible

I have a basic playbook to restart an Apache server but I'm wondering how the following command is interpreted and converted to its equivalent -- `service httpd start`.

```
- name: ensure apache is running
    service:
      name: httpd
      state: started
```

Comment: I have added the actual code snippet to show what happens for `state: started`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service` module first gets the status of the service (httpd). If the service is `started` or `running` or `reloaded` and the desired service state is `started`, it will not restart the service.

```
self.svc_change = False
...
...
if not self.running and self.state in ["started", "running", "reloaded"]:
    self.svc_change = True
```

If you want to restart:

```
state: restarted   ==>  service httpd restart
```

[service - Manage services](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html)

- started/stopped are idempotent actions that will not run commands unless necessary
- restarted will always bounce the service
- reloaded will always reload